# How to create fat static library for an Android application on MacOS?

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-libraries

I'm trying to build static FAT library for Android NDK which should contain armv6 and armv7 versions.

Tried libtool - doesn't help, cause on MacOS it is not compatible with Android ABI.

Tried ranlib that I found in my NDK folder also with no success.

As an option could someone explain how should I use Android.mk to specify an appropriate library for an architecture.

Answer (score 2):

On Android you don't (at least currently) create fat binaries. Instead, your APK will contain 1:n binaries for the architectures you wish to support.

Your Application.mk (preferred) or Android.mk should define a APP_ABI variable for the architecture(s)

For example, to support ARM (generic) and ARMv7a:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

See $(NDK)/docs/APPLICATION-MK.txt for more information.